# Nested sort in SELECT followed by Conditional INSERT based upon results of SELECT inquiry

Tags: mysql

I have been struggling with the following for some time.
The server I am using has MySQL ver 5.7 installed.

**The issue:**
I wish to take recorded tank level readings from one table, find the difference between the last two records for a particular tank, and multiply this by a factor to get a quantity used.
The extracted quantity, if it is +ve, else 0 , then to be inserted into another table for further use.

The Quant value extracted may be +ve or -ve as tanks fill and empty. I only require the used quantity -ie falling level.

The two following tables are used:

Table 'tf_rdgs' sample;
value 1 is content height.

| id | location | value1 | reading_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 1500 |  |
| 2 | 18 | 1340 |  |
| 3 | 9 | 1600 |  |
| 4 | 18 | 1200 |  |
| 5 | 9 | 1400 |  |
| 6 | 18 | 1765 | yyyy |
| 7 | 18 | 1642 | xxxx |

Table 'flow' example

| id | location | Quant | reading_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 5634 | dd-mm: HH-mm |
| 2 | 18 | 0 | dd-mm: HH-mm |
| 3 | 18 | 123 | current time |

I do not require to go back over history and am only interested in the latest level readings as a new level reading is inserted.

I can get the following to work with a table of only one location.

```
INSERT INTO flow (location, Quant) 
SELECT t1.location, (t2.value1 - t1.value1) AS Quant 
FROM tf_rdgs t1 cross join tf_rdgs t2 on t1.reading_time > t2.reading_time 
ORDER BY t2.reading_time DESC limit 1
```

It is not particularly efficient but works and gives the following return from the above table.

| location | Quant |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 123 |

for a table with mixed locations including a `WHERE t1.location = ...` statement does not work.

The problems i am struggling with are

1. How to nest the initial sorting by location for the subsequent inquiry of difference between the last two tank level readings.
   A singular location search is ok rather than all tanks.
2. A Conditional INSERT to insert the 'Quant' value only if it is +ve or else insert a 0 if it is -ve (ie filling)

I have tried many permutations on these without success.

3. Once the above has been achieved it needs to run on a conditional trigger - based upon location of inserted data - in the tf_rdgs table activated upon each new reading inserted from the sensors on a particular tank.

I can achieve the above with the exception of the conditional insert if each tank had a dedicated table but unfortunately I cant go there due existing data structure and usage.

Any direction or assitance on parts or whole of this much appreciated.

Comment: What's a tank - there is no such column in the sample data..Also does date matter when you have what appears to be an id which could be used for establishing last 2?

Comment: Water tanks in an agricultural situation. Example table is simplified. Tanks identified by location  but there may be several tanks at that location which become value 2, value3 etc. These not included to avoid confusion.  Time is important as ultimate usage is time logged to determine (as an example) remaining reserve in each tank.  Can use id  to determine last tanks but same issue as with time sort -  unlikley id's will be consecutive for particular location readings